# Can we use app_src as source to take multiple snapshots in gstreamer?

Tags: rust, gstreamer, video-processing, gstreamer-rs

I am new to gstreamer and rust. I am trying to write an app for taking **multiple** snapshots while transferring video stream to learn more about gstreamer and rust. It is common for us to transferring videos via NFS, SMB, SSH or S3, and I would like to write an app to transfer files, and takes multiple snapshots before writing to files in disk or uploading to somewhere else. Please keep in mind that I would like to take multiple snapshots of the entire video instead of one, so taking one snapshot and quit is not an option. Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to use something like https://github.com/amzn/amazon-s3-gst-plugin to load s3 stream (while transferring file) as app_src and call pull_image() for snapshots? So I only need to allocate (heap) memory less that the size of the video.
2. If 1. is not possible, can I load the load a video into memory(vec! -> gst::Buffer::from_slice) as app_src and then call pull_image() for snapshots? In this case, I have to allocate (heap) memory at least the size of the video.

When I run the following code:

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(dead_code)]
use gst::element_error;
use gst::prelude::*;

use anyhow::Error;
use apng::{load_dynamic_image, Encoder, Frame, PNGImage};
use clap::{Arg, ArgAction, Command};
use derive_more::{Display, Error};
use image::{GenericImage, ImageBuffer, ImageFormat, Rgb, RgbImage};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Read};
use std::iter::once;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use substring::Substring;
use vfs::{MemoryFS, VfsPath};

extern crate pretty_env_logger;
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

#[derive(Debug, Display, Error)]
#[display(fmt = "Missing element {}", _0)]
struct MissingElement(#[error(not(source))] &'static str);

#[derive(Debug, Display, Error)]
#[display(fmt = "Received error from {}: {} (debug: {:?})", src, error, debug)]
struct ErrorMessage {
    src: String,
    error: String,
    debug: Option<glib::GString>,
    source: glib::Error,
}

const SNAPSHOT_HEIGHT: u32 = 240;
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
struct Snapshooter {
    src_uri: String,
    shot_total: u8,
    img_buffer_list: Option<Vec<ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>>>,
}

fn get_file_as_gst_buf_by_slice(filename: &String) -> gst::Buffer {
    let mut f = File::open(&filename).expect("no file found");
    let metadata = std::fs::metadata(&filename).expect("unable to read metadata");
    let mut buffer = vec![0; metadata.len() as usize];
    f.read_to_end(&mut buffer).expect("buffer overflow");
    gst::Buffer::from_slice(buffer)
}

fn get_pipeline_from_appsrc(uri: String) -> Result<gst::Pipeline, Error> {
    // this line will hang: let sample = appsink.pull_sample().map_err(|_| gst::FlowError::Eos)?;
    let vid_buf = get_file_as_gst_buf_by_slice(&uri);
    info!("vid buf size: {:?}", vid_buf.size());

    // declaring pipeline
    let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::new(None);
    let src = gst::ElementFactory::make("appsrc")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not build element uridecodebin");
    let decodebin = gst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not create decodebin element");
    let glup = gst::ElementFactory::make("videoconvert")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not build element videoconvert");
    let sink = gst::ElementFactory::make("appsink")
        .name("sink")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not build element appsink");
    pipeline
        .add_many(&[&src, &decodebin, &glup, &sink])
        .unwrap();
    //gst::Element::link_many(&[&src, &glup, &sink]).unwrap();
    info!("declaring pipeline done");

    src.link(&decodebin)?;
    let glup_weak = glup.downgrade();
    decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
        let sink_pad = match glup_weak.upgrade() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => s.static_pad("sink").expect("cannot get sink pad from sink"),
        };

        src_pad
            .link(&sink_pad)
            .expect("Cannot link the decodebin source pad to the glup sink pad");
    });
    //gst::Element::link(&src, &glup).expect("could not link src and glup");
    gst::Element::link(&glup, &sink)?;
    info!("link pipeline done");

    let appsrc = src
        .dynamic_cast::<gst_app::AppSrc>()
        .expect("Source element is expected to be an appsrc!");
    info!("appsrc cast done");
    appsrc
        .push_buffer(vid_buf)
        .expect("Unable to push to appsrc's buffer");
    info!("push to appsrc done");
    Ok(pipeline)
}

fn get_pipeline_from_filesrc(uri: String) -> Result<gst::Pipeline, Error> {
    // declaring pipeline
    let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::new(None);
    let src = gst::ElementFactory::make("filesrc")
        .property_from_str("location", uri.as_str())
        .build()
        .expect("Could not build element uridecodebin");
    let decodebin = gst::ElementFactory::make("decodebin")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not create decodebin element");
    let glup = gst::ElementFactory::make("videoconvert")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not build element videoconvert");
    let sink = gst::ElementFactory::make("appsink")
        .name("sink")
        .build()
        .expect("Could not build element appsink");
    pipeline
        .add_many(&[&src, &decodebin, &glup, &sink])
        .unwrap();
    //gst::Element::link_many(&[&src, &glup, &sink]).unwrap();

    src.link(&decodebin)?;
    let glup_weak = glup.downgrade();
    decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |_, src_pad| {
        let sink_pad = match glup_weak.upgrade() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => s.static_pad("sink").expect("cannot get sink pad from sink"),
        };

        src_pad
            .link(&sink_pad)
            .expect("Cannot link the decodebin source pad to the glup sink pad");
    });
    //gst::Element::link(&src, &glup).expect("could not link src and glup");
    gst::Element::link(&glup, &sink)?;
    Ok(pipeline)
}

impl Snapshooter {
    fn new(src_path: String, shot_total: u8, is_include_org_name: bool) -> Snapshooter {
        Snapshooter {
            src_uri: src_path.clone(),
            shot_total: shot_total,
            img_buffer_list: None,
        }
    }

    fn extract_snapshot_list(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Self, Error> {
        gst::init()?;

        // Create our pipeline from a pipeline description string.
        //let pipeline = get_pipeline_from_filesrc(self.src_uri.clone())?
        let pipeline = get_pipeline_from_appsrc(self.src_uri.clone())?
            .downcast::<gst::Pipeline>()
            .expect("Expected a gst::Pipeline");

        // Get access to the appsink element.
        let mut appsink = pipeline
            .by_name("sink")
            .expect("Sink element not found")
            .downcast::<gst_app::AppSink>()
            .expect("Sink element is expected to be an appsink!");

        // Don't synchronize on the clock, we only want a snapshot asap.
        appsink.set_property("sync", false);

        // Tell the appsink what format we want.
        // This can be set after linking the two objects, because format negotiation between
        // both elements will happen during pre-rolling of the pipeline.
        appsink.set_caps(Some(
            &gst::Caps::builder("video/x-raw")
                .field("format", gst_video::VideoFormat::Rgbx.to_str())
                .build(),
        ));

        pipeline
            .set_state(gst::State::Playing)
            .expect("Can't set the pipeline's state into playing");

        // Pull the sample in question out of the appsink's buffer.
        let sample = appsink.pull_sample().map_err(|_| gst::FlowError::Eos)?;

        info!("Finished sample buffer 1");

        sample.buffer().ok_or_else(|| {
            element_error!(
                appsink,
                gst::ResourceError::Failed,
                ("Failed to get buffer from appsink")
            );

            gst::FlowError::Error
        })?;

        info!("Finished sample buffer 2");

        let total_in_sec = pipeline
            .query_duration::<gst::ClockTime>()
            .unwrap()
            .seconds();

        self.img_buffer_list = Some(
            (1..self.shot_total + 1)
                .collect::<Vec<u8>>()
                .into_iter()
                .map(|img_counter| {
                    take_snapshot(
                        &mut appsink,
                        total_in_sec,
                        self.shot_total.into(),
                        img_counter.into(),
                    )
                    .unwrap()
                })
                .collect(),
        );

        Ok(self)
    }
}

fn take_snapshot(
    appsink: &mut gst_app::AppSink,
    total_in_sec: u64,
    shot_total: u64,
    img_counter: u64,
) -> Result<ImageBuffer<Rgb<u8>, Vec<u8>>, Error> {
    Ok(ImageBuffer::new(8, 8))
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(_) = std::env::var("RUST_LOG") {
        std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info");
    }
    pretty_env_logger::init();
    use std::env;

    let cli_matches = Command::new(env!("CARGO_CRATE_NAME"))
        .arg_required_else_help(true)
        .arg(
            Arg::new("is_include_org_name")
                .long("is-include-org-name")
                .global(true)
                .action(ArgAction::SetFalse),
        )
        .arg(Arg::new("uri").help("No input URI provided on the commandline"))
        .arg(
            clap::Arg::new("shot_total")
                .long("shot-total")
                .value_parser(clap::value_parser!(u8).range(1..255))
                .action(clap::ArgAction::Set)
                .required(true),
        )
        .get_matches();

    Snapshooter::new(
        cli_matches.get_one::<String>("uri").unwrap().to_string(),
        *cli_matches.get_one("shot_total").unwrap(),
        *cli_matches.get_one("is_include_org_name").unwrap(),
    )
    .extract_snapshot_list()
    .unwrap();
}
```

My app hang in appsink.pull_sample() (line 194) for a 5s video indefinitely without any error. 3) Any idea please?

Since my app_src approach hit a wall, before asking in here. I tried to fall back to the filesrc approach. When I disable line 166 and enable to 165 to try the filesrc approach, I got the WasLinked error:

Running `target/debug/gsnapshot --shot-total 4 /tmp/sample-10s.mp4`

```
     thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Cannot link the decodebin source pad to the glup sink pad: WasLinked', src/main.rs:145:14
     note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
     fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
```

The strange part is when I run the code against one video, I can generate snapshots, but most videos I tried yield the WasLinked Error. 4) Does anyone know what happens?

Thanks a lot for your time and patient. Any suggestions and tips are welcome.

PS:

a) I clean up some of the irrelevant part of the code

b) Test videos: https://samplelib.com/sample-mp4.html

c)

```
[dependencies]
gst = { package = "gstreamer", git = "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs" }
gst-base = { package = "gstreamer-base", git = "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs" }
gst-app = { package = "gstreamer-app", git = "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs" }
gst-video = { package = "gstreamer-video", git = "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs" }
image = { version="*"}
anyhow = "1.0"
derive_more = "0.99.5"
glib = { git = "https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core" }
vfs = "*"

substring = "1.4.5"

# Cfg
clap = { version = "3.x" }

# Util + Console
log = "0.4"
pretty_env_logger = "0.4"
```